# Scroll smoothly down and hide scroll bars

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, jquery-animate, scrollbar

I have a page with 2 div's(#page1 and #page2 above each other which are exactly the size of the browser window(calculated by jQuery). When I click on the div with id: name I want the page to scroll smoothly down to #page2. This is al working fine.

But now I want to hide the scrollbars and stop users to be able to scroll. So the only way users can go down to the page is by clicking on the #name div. But when I try setting the body to overflow: hidden the page won't scroll anymore to #page2. Only when I take out the animation and only use scrollIntoView. Then it jumps to #page2. Here is my code:

```
$('#name').click(function() {
    //$('#page2')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
    $('#page2').scrollTo(500);
});


jQuery.fn.extend(
{
  scrollTo : function(speed, easing)
  {
    return this.each(function()
    {
      var targetOffset = $(this).offset().top;
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, speed, easing);
    });
  }
});
```

How can I combine both, the animation and the overflow: hidden?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will Smoothly Scroll You to the 300PX from Top :

```
   jQuery('html,body').stop().animate({  scrollTop:  300 }, 400, function () {});
```

and for disabling the Scrollbar

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden')
```